# <3>WSL (358) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:789: Failed to translate Z:/

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having some problems using Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS). I need to access a folder I have accessed locally by mapping a network drive.

I have installed both WSL and Ubuntu from the Microsoft App Store. I have been using this system for months and never encountered a problem.

Since yesterday, when trying to open a Linux terminal for the folder in the drive I mapped, I get this error:

```
<3>WSL (358) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:789: Failed to translate Z:/
```

I do not encounter the same problem when opening a Linux Terminal in any other folder such as Desktop, or anything local.

I am not familiar with these kinds of errors, so anything to try would help a lot.

Comment: _when trying to open a Linux terminal for the folder_ : It would make to sense if you would post the statement which causes the error. Since you are running bash, you could produce a trace of the bash startup files. Further, you did not say whether you got at least a working _bash_ shell after seeing this error message.

Comment: Please forgive me as I am not too familiar with this. After installing the WSL and Ubuntu on Windows you can right click on any folder and open a Linux shell. So I have no command line to show for this. In the section 'This PC' I can see the Network Drive I mapped, so I usually right-clicked there and chose 'Open Linux shell here'. That allowed me to use Linux within the Network Drive.

Comment: Well, **do** you get a shell after the error? Or does the error just pop up and then the window is closed? You really better describe the behaviour in more detail.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, I am not familiar with these errors, so I am trying to describe it as best as I can. The shell does open, however after the error all I see is username: ~$ and when trying ls I get no output. Please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide you with.

Comment: Good to know that the shell opens. From this, I would do, for debugging, the following tests: (1) Inside the shell, which you now got, can you do a `cd` to your mapped network drive? (2) If this works and you don't see again an error message, then, after this `cd`,  create a new non-login shell using just the command`bash` - do you **then** get an error message?

Answer (score 24):

You are most probably using Docker Desktop, Docker Dekstop makes it own distro and sets it as default, this is what causes the issue.

To make the default distro you mount to you can change it using the following command

```bash
wsl --list
wsl --setdefault <DISTRO_NAME>
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: This is not the answer, and it doesn't matter what distro is being used. I have the same problem as the OP, and I'm not using Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The `Z` drive is likely not mounted.

```
sudo mount -t drvfs Z: /mnt/z
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you've been using Visual Studio Code in combination with WSL?

I've encountered a similar error message (amongst others) after updating to Visual Studio Code 1.85.1:

```
<3>WSL (2559) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:708: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
```

For me that problem was solved by starting Visual Studio Code from a WSL Terminal:

```
$ code .
```

Thereby the VS Code Server got updated automatically:

```
Updating VS Code Server to version 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2)
Downloading: 100%
Unpacking: 100%
Unpacked 1530 files and folders to /home/mneutzner/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2.
```

Thereafter WSL started successfully and all folders were accessible again.